# Importing a go project in Goland

Tags: go, goland

I am trying to use the goland ide for my go project. My project directory structure is like this

```
/Users/me/workspace/src/github.com/mynamespace/myproject
```

Now the myproject directory consists of a glide.yaml file which downloads all the dependencies inside the vendor folder when I do

```
glide install
```

So the vendor path will be

```
/Users/me/workspace/src/github.com/mynamespace/myproject/vendor
```

Now I opened the project in the GoLand IDE. However, the sources have a bunch of import statements like

```
import "github.com/mynamespace/anotherproject"
```

which are marked as red. This means the GoLand IDE was not able to pick them up from the vendor folder.

Could you please let me know how can I import these dependencies in the IDE?

Comment: this may help: https://glamanate.com/blog/goland-ide-and-local-vendor-directories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose Open Directory and select `/Users/me/workspace/src/github.com/mynamespace/myproject` as the directory to open and the IDE will pick up everything in it.

Then, you need to make sure that the IDE has the correct configuration for the GOPATH. To do so, go to Settings | Go | GOPATH and choose either the `Global GOPATH` (used across projects), or the `Project GOPATH` to be `/Users/me/workspace`.

Answer (score 0):

`GoLand` picks up the Go env vars so add these to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
### Go ###
export WORKSPACE=/Users/me/workspace/go  # <= In your case without the /go
export GOPATH=$WORKSPACE
export GOBIN=$WORKSPACE/bin
export PATH="$PATH:$GOBIN"
```

With these you should be able to build and run Go programs within or outside of GoLand.